# Shopify Theme Development - Edits to one collection affect all collections using same template

Tags: templates, themes, shopify, shopify-template

I have built a couple collection templates - in this instance I am editing one called 'collection.brand.liquid', placing sections through out this collection template so the content can be edited in the wysiwig editor for each collection.

If I update one of the collections it changes for them all.

Surely they don't want me to have 300 collection templates?

collection.brand.liquid:

```
{% section 'slider-brand-informative' %}

<div class="section brand-page-section">
    <div class="section-inner">
        {% section 'block-brand-introduction' %}

        {% section 'block-brand-slanty' %}

        {% section 'block-brand-slanty-additional' %}

        {% section 'block-brand-chunky' %}

        {% section 'block-brand-chunky-additional' %}

        {% section 'block-brand-featured-news' %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Example content section:

```
<div class="section brand-page-introduction-section">
    <div class="section-inner">

        {% if section.settings.brand-page-logo %}
            <div class="brand-logo-contain">
                <img class="brand-logo" alt="Brand Logo" src="{{ section.settings.brand-page-logo | img_url: 'medium' }}">
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if section.settings.brand-page-brand-name %}
            <div class="brand-name">
                <h1 class="brand-title">{{ section.settings.brand-page-brand-name }}</h1>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        <div class="brand-description">

            {{ section.settings.brand-page-brand-description }}
            
        </div>

        <div class="brand-view-more-button">
            <a href="{{ section.settings.brand-page-brand-all-products }}" class="box-link"></a>
            <h4 class="brand-view-more-button-text">VIEW ALL PRODUCTS</h4>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
{% schema %}
    {
        "name": "Brand Page Introduction",
        "settings": [
            {
                "id": "brand-page-logo",
                "type": "image_picker",
                "label": "Brand Logo"
            },
            {
                "id": "brand-page-brand-name",
                "type": "text",
                "label": "Brand Name",
                "default": "Brand Name"
            },
            {
                "id": "brand-page-brand-description",
                "type": "richtext",
                "label": "Add description",
                "default": "<p>Brand Description</p>"
            },
            {
                "id": "brand-page-brand-all-products",
                "type": "url",
                "label": "Brand All Products Link"
            }
        ]
    }
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

Has anyone else had trouble with this? - creating multiple collections from one collection template replaces content in previous uses of the template?

How can I get this working?

Comment: Looks like a browser related issue. Try in a different browser

Comment: I eventually received a response from Shopify basically saying they use templates for this purpose, and haven't got it working on collections yet. So I now have 100+ collection templates and even more sections duplicated for each. Easily one of my least favourite CMS's.

Comment: Metafields can be used to add extra info to the collection instead of creating so many templates